# Server Error in '/' Application. Error while Compiling the Code

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc

I am often getting this error

**`<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="xxx.MvcApplication" Language="C#"%>`**

Did i miss anything in my code??

```
Error   6   The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary' (are you missing an assembly reference?)C:\Users\Administrator\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\xxx\xxx\Controllers\BaseController.cs    7   45  xxx
```

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Find the type or namespace "Data" in BaseController.cs, and make sure you are referencing the correct assembly.
also, right-click the project in visual studio and make sure all the references in the project are ok, you'll see a warning sign beside any reference that can't be found.   if there are any missing references, open up project properties > reference paths > add the folder to the relevant assembly.